# Question regarding an absolute value proof

Tags: real-analysis

While reading a proof, I came across this statement: "let ${s_n}$ be a sequence of real numbers that converges to the value s. If we choose m such that $|s_n - s| \lt \frac12|s|$ when $n \geq m$, then we see that $|s_n| \gt \frac12|s|$ when $n \geq m$". I tried using the fact that $|s_n - s| \leq |s_n| + |s|$ but this didn't get me anywhere. Can you show me how to formally prove this statement?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$s=(s-s_n)+s_n$ implies that $|s|\le|s-s_n|+|s_n|$ wich leads to: $|s|<\frac{1}{2}|s|+|s_n|$ or equivalently $|s_n|>\frac{1}{2}|s|$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: saying that  $s_n\to s$ is equivalent to saying that $|s_n-s|\to 0$. Then use triangle inequality for $|s_n|=|s -(s-s_n)|$.

Answer (score 0):

$$|s_n|=|s-(s-s_n)|\ge |s|-|s-s_n|>|s|-\frac{1}{2}|s|=\frac12|s|$$